# Is it possible to define how an enum is (de-)serialized for persistence inside the enum?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project using JPA and hibernate.

Let's say there is an enum `Code` that represents a simple http status code:

```java
public enum Code {
  OK,
  NOT_FOUND
}
```

Let's say there is a converter for this enum called `CodeConverter`:

```java
@Converter
public class CodeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Code, Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Code code) {
    if (code == Code.OK) return 200;
    if (code == Code.NOT_FOUND) return 404;
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Code convertToEntityAttribute(Integer integer) {
    if (integer == 200) return Code.OK;
    if (integer == 404) return Code.NOT_FOUND;
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Without knowing what entites use `Code`, can I specify inside `Code` that `Code` should always be (de-)serialized using `CodeConverter`?** E.g.:

```java
@UseConverter(CodeConverter.class)
public enum Code {
...
```

I know about `@Converter(autoApply = true)` annotation for `CodeConverter`, but afaik this only works when the `CodeConverter` is scanned by `@EntityScan` in the Spring Boot configuration. And for my use case, I can not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of JPA you are using you may consider using **@PostLoad** and **@PrePersist** to do the translations you need:

This article shows a good example:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

Comment: `PostLoad` and `PrePersist` must be annotated on an entity, correct? In my use case, I do not know about the entities using `Code`. `Code` itself is not an entity, it is just an enum that will be part of some entites. But, in my use case, these entities remain unknown.